# Scrollable flex column pushes document height over 100%, resulting in 2 scrollbars

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox with 2 rows. In the second row I have a flexbox with 2 columns and the second column becomes scrollable when the content overflows. However, when it becomes scrollable, the document becomes scrollable also (a tiny bit - as if the first row's height is added to the document's height).

I have set 100% heights to all parents and debugged a lot but couldn't fix this. I can't see what's going wrong.

I duplicated the issue in this Js Bin: https://jsbin.com/lesoledoqo/1/edit?html,output

Any ideas?

Code:

```html
<html style="height: 100%;">

<body style="height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
   <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%;">
      <div style=" background-color: gray">
         Content 1
      </div>
      <div style="display: flex; background-color: green; height: 100%;">
         <div style="background-color: blue;">
            Content 2.1
         </div>
         <div style="background-color: yellow; height: 100%; overflow-y: auto;">
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
                        Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
                        Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
                        Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
                       Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
                       Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
                       Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
                       Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2<br />
            Content 2.2
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add `min-height: 0` to the nested flex container. https://jsbin.com/ruzukeroda/edit?html,output

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin thank you, that worked! I've also read the duplicate question's answer which provides this solution. However, could you elaborate a bit why did the second row's min-height grow bigger when the yellow row's scrollbar appeared?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code and its behaviour, it's working as coded.

If you want a scroll bar on second row's column only NOT on the entire document, then do it this way -

1. give some fixed height to first row, let's say 40px
2. and then give 100vh - 40px height to the second row, using CSS's calc() method.

vh - view height

Demo [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/sj_shyam_joshi/y2hjgbkL/15/)

```
height: calc(100vh - 40px);
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I would avoid this if possible because I want to keep the first row's height flexible